# How to Get value in Dropdown (Custom product Attribute).

Tags: magento-1.9, database, product-attribute

I want to get value from the database (which is created custom module) in dropdown which is custom product attribute.

Answer (score 1):

that seems to be working fine here:

```
require "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app();
$sku = "178934";

// Get data from shop: 
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku);
$products->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(1);
$products->load();

$product        = $products->getFirstItem();
$attribute      = $product->getAttributes();
$my_attribute   = $attribute['my_attribute']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

echo "\n sku: " . $sku . ' - my_attribute: ' . $my_attribute;
```